# Backbone trouble with calling functions

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, cordova

I'm very inexperienced with javascript so forgive me if this is really obvious...

I'm using the TodoMVC example found here (http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/) as a foundation for a Cordova project. The trouble that I'm having is combining this with the Camera and Geolocation plugins, I get errors calling any functions in js/views/app-view.js from within the Camera/Geolocation callback functions. I'm assuming it's a problem of context but I don't know enough about javascript to fix it.

For example, the TodoMVC project adds new items using this line of code, in js\views\app-view.js:

```
app.todos.create(this.newAttributes());
```

I'm trying to combine this with the camera function to take a picture with a phone's camera, then add a new todo item with the picture stored in it. Everything works fine except when I try to have that above line of code in the camera callback function, at the bottom like this:

```
onCameraSuccess: function(imageData) {
        // Stores image data in a hidden field to be used later. Not best method but it works
        document.getElementById('imageData').value =  "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

        // This line should create a new item
        app.todos.create(this.newAttributes());
    },
```

It gives the error "Undefined is not a function", seemingly referring to "this.newAttributes()". Again it seems like this is a matter of context, because that very same line works almost anywhere else in the same script.

OnCameraSuccess is a callback function from the Camera's getPicture function:

```
Camera: function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onCameraSuccess, this.onCameraFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            targetWidth: 250,
            targetHeight: 250,
            correctOrientation: true
        });
    },
```

Likewise, a function for Geolocation requires two callback functions, for success and errors, but I can't find an acceptable way to refer to the other functions that doesn't give a TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR that says those aren't functions.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        //This line calls the geolocation function and specifies the two callback functions, but it thinks they don't exist
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.onLocationSuccess, this.onLocationError, {enableHighAccuracy : true});
    },

    onLocationSuccess: function(position) {
        // map logic
    },

    onLocationError: function(error) {
        alert('code: ' +error.code+ '\n' + 'message: ' +error.message + '\n');
    },
```

They're right below the onDeviceReady function, but for some reason it can't find them. this.onLocationSuccess doesn't work (even though that's how it refers to all of its other functions), self.onLocationSuccess doesn't work... Again, it seems like a matter of context, but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas? I don't even know enough about javascript to know if I'm explaining this adequately, so feel free to yell at me about that too.

Comment: Oh right, onCameraSuccess is a callback function from the Camera's getPicture function. I edited that code into the middle of the original post. All of these functions are in the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` in JavaScript depends on how a function is called. For example, this:

```
var obj = {
    f: function() { console.log(this) }
};
obj.f();
```

will put `obj` in the console but this:

```
var obj = {
    f: function() { console.log(this) }
};
var f = obj.f;
f();
```

will (usually) dump `window` into the console even though the same function is being called. This `this` behavior confuses almost everyone when they start using JavaScript. In your case, the documentation doesn't say anything about what `this` will be in the `getPicture` callbacks so `this` is probably going to be `window` instead of your object.

If you need a particular `this` with a callback function in JavaScript, you usually have to arrange it yourself. One way to do that is to stash the desired `this` in a variable and use an anonymous function:

```
var _this = this;
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function(imageData) { _this.onCameraSuccess(imageData) },
    ...
);
```

A cleaner way (especially when there are arguments to your functions) is to bind the function to the desired `this` using [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), or similar utilities that come with pretty much every JavaScript toolkit. For example, given this:

```
var obj = {
    f: function() { console.log(this) }
};
var f1 = $.proxy(obj.f, obj);
var f2 = _(obj.f).bind(obj);
var f3 = obj.f.bind(obj);
```

Calling `f1()`, `f2()`, or `f3()` will all dump `obj` into the console. Underscore is the typical toolkit with Backbone so this would be common:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    _(this.onCameraSuccess).bind(this),
    _(this.onCameraFail).bind(this),
    { ... }
);
```

Underscore also provides [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), this is commonly used within `initialize` to bind several functions in-place:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'onCameraSuccess', 'onCameraFail');
    //...
}
```

and then you can use `this.onCameraSuccess` without worry about the binding:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    this.onCameraSuccess,
    this.onCameraFail,
    { ... }
);
```

Using `_.bindAll` in `initialize` would probably be the most common approach in Backbone.

Comment: Very enlightening, I understand 'this' a lot better now. And the _.bindAll fix works perfectly, both the Camera and Geolocation are totally functional. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Since you are passing this as a reference to the camera function it is being overridden by camera's context with the current context of the application.

Make a clone of the current context like

```
var currentContext = this;
currentContext.onCameraSuccess,
currentContext.onCameraFail
```

This is applicable where ever the application control is moving from one context to other eg:backbone view to underscore functions and moving back to callback function etc.

Comment: This won't work. `currentContext.onCameraSuccess` will behave exactly the same as `this.onCameraSuccess` when the function gets called. You'd have to use an anonymous function wrapper (`function(x) { currentContext.onCameraSuccess(x) }`) for `currentContext` to be useful.